# Is there a test Suite for netcat (nc)?

Tags: openbsd, testing

Is there a test suite available for the openbsd implementation of netcat?
A POSIX compatible test suite would also suffice.
Specfically for functional testing. I'm trying to play with the pledges in netcat and want to ensure functional correctness.

Comment: nc/ncat/netcat is not posix. All nc implementations have a lot of incompatible quirks, limitations and useless incomplete featurelets, so if you're writing your own, you'll have to try hard to do worse ;-)

Comment: I'm actually looking at refactoring bits of the OpenBSD netcat. (editing question to include this info). I'm hoping for a test suite specific to OpenBSD.

Comment: I don't see anything in their `src/regress/usr.bin` -- maybe you should ask them directly?

Comment: I did put a mail out on misc@OpenBSD.